# Обращение к Ajax ответу, полученному в виде HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть Ajax запрос, ответ приходит в формате JSON. В ответе есть HTML блок с классом `count-order`, который вставляется в общее поле `#result-list`:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json', 
}).done(function(result) { 
    $("#result-list").append(result.name).fadeIn('fast'); 
})
```

Каким образом можно обратиться к полученному в ответе блоку `.count-order`, чтобы "не задеть" остальные блоки с этим же классом?

Т.е. нужно что-то похожее на:

```
var textCout = $(this).find(".count-order").text();
$(this).find(".class_123").append(' <span class="label ">' + textCout + '</span>');
```

В данном случае `$(this)` написано условно. Вместо функции `.append()` пробовал использовать `.appendTo()`, но выдается ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
var resq = $(result.name);
$("#result_list").append(resq);
var textCout = resq.find(".count-order").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Псевдокод:

```
$(".count-order").addClass("old");

//тут вызывается и вставляется ajax
//после чего обращаемся ко всем каунт-ордерам, кроме старых
var newBlocks = $(".count-order:not(.old)");

//альтернативный код, если выше не понятно:
var newBlocks - $('.count-order').not('.old');
```

Comment: по две штуки добавлются

Comment: Ок, тогда просто перед вызовом ajax-запроса назначь всем старым элементам класс old, добавь новые, обратись к ним. И так по кругу, намылить-смыть-повторить.